# BMW CAN bus data format

Tags: engine, obd-ii, bmw, dtc, can-bus

https://www.reddit.com/r/CANBus/comments/39pzpp/bmw_3series_2015_odometer_reading/
I am using the above website as reference and sending commands to engine ECU. I have a log from BMW engine ECU (below):

```
6F1 12 04 18 02 FF FF
6F1 12 04 18 02 FF FF 
612 F1 10 17 58 07 4D FF 21 <DATA ERROR
6F1 12 30 00 00 
612 F1 21 49 93 21 4A B8 21 <DATA ERROR
612 F1 22 4B F8 21 49 A3 21 <DATA ERROR
612 F1 23 4C B4 21 4C 18 21 <DATA ERROR
```

The log shows that 6F1 is the address for query to the engine ECU and 612 is the address for engine ECU response

Below are the Commands I send using PuTTY (similar to HyperTerminal):

```
AT Z (reset)
Reply: OK
AT SP 6 (set protocol 6, i.e. CAN 11/500)
Reply: OK
AT SH 6F1 (set header to 6F1)
Reply: OK
AT CRA 612 (receiver address set to 612 for engine)
Reply: OK
12 04 18 02 FF FF
Reply: NO DATA
12 18 02 FF FF
Reply: NO DATA
18 02 FF FF
Reply: NO DATA
```

I have tried all possible combinations but can't get the fault code. Can someone tell me the exact command I should hit to get BMW engine DTC?

Answer (score -1):

In turn, 'nodes' or 'electronic control units' (ECUs) are like parts of the body, interconnected via the CAN bus. Information sensed by one part can be shared with another. see full details [DTC on a BMW?](https://dirtsound.com/dtc-on-bmw/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/64714)